# Why does a delegate assigned an instance method store the instance object?

Tags: c#, delegates, il

The `method` is already the address (it's an `int`) of the location to begin execution. Presumably this address is associated with the object instance it relates to, so why does the delegate need the object (`Target`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the target was not stored. What should invoking a delegate to an instance method do? An instance method cannot run without an object reference that is the current instance (the `this` reference in C#). It is not possible to define a sensible behavior for this case.

An instance method can access instance fields. Without the `this` reference these fields would be inaccessible.

If you do not want to store the target, wrap the instance method in a static function:

```
MyCustomClass obj = new MyCustomClass();
Action withTarget = obj.SomeMethod; //stores target

static void MyCustomInvoker(MyCustomClass obj) {
 obj.SomeMethod();
}

Action<MyCustomClass> noTarget = MyCustomInvoker; //does not store any target
```

Comment: I was reading something about that. So is `this` passed as a hidden first parameter to the instance method?

Comment: @RichardDesLonde exactly. In IL it is accessed as `ldarg.0` just like any other method argument. When invoking an instance method through a delegate the CLR generates instructions to make the target the first argument at runtime.

Comment: Is that called closure, because the instance method has access to non-local variable?

Comment: I edited the code snippet a bit. No closures here. The delegate binds directly to the method and target.

Comment: So, forgetting delegates for a minute...what happens in a typical scenario when you call `obj.SomeMethod()`...is `SomeMethod()` getting a reference to `this`?

Comment: Yes because SomeMethod might use instance fields.

Comment: Ok so the clr generates instructions to make the target the first argument at runtime, just like with the delegate?

Comment: Yes. Under the hood instance methods do not exist. At the x86 level they behave like static method with an additional parameter. The case is more complex with delegates because it is not statically known whether the delegate points to a static or an instance method. The CLR must switch at runtime on that fact and either prepend the Target argument, or not. This is actually a cause for performance differences between the two cases.

Comment: If you're using reflection (in the form of `Delegate.CreateDelegate()`), you don't even need the static wrapper, you could create `Action<MyCustomClass>` directly from `SomeMethod`.